# How to convert a multi-line text file into a single line text file

Tags: excel, xml, csv, file-conversion

Firstly, i've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177084/convert-multi-line-output-into-single-line), and elsewhere on the web but I can't really find what I'm looking for.

I have an alarm / access control system that takes a single, continuous/contiguous line of xml as a config file. There's hundreds of 'lines' if you open it in a text editor like notepad. BUT - *it's actually all on one line* - no carriage returns anywhere.

Now, I want to add users in a list (there's over 200 users) and I have found the place in the XML where I need to insert all the details. I have an excel spreadsheet with the names, permissions etc, and I've converted that to a CSV. Now I need to remove each and every carriage return from the text before I paste it into the Config file.

I'm not using any server type software, C# or Javascript or any such. All I've got is Excel and Notepad. I don't mind parsing the CSV with a program or tool, but it must give me a single, contiguous line output from my multi-line CSV

Is there a method other than manually going through the file and hitting delete on every single carriage return?

***EDIT***

Expected Output (Sample of XML copied from Notepad):

```
<user id="1"><name>Bevan</name><pin>xxxx</pin><tag>xxxxxxxx</tag><type><opt id="kbdortag">Keypad or Tag</opt></type><partns><pn id="1" /><pn id="2" /></partns><access><opt id="awarm" /><opt id="awdis" /><opt id="stdis" /><opt id="egrs" /><opt id="view" /></access><priv><opt id="own" /><opt id="otr" /><opt id="all" /><opt id="phn" /><opt id="clk" /><opt id="dtmf" /><opt id="lrn" /><opt id="cbk" /></priv><misc /><tzs /><kps><kp id="1" /><kp id="2" /><kp id="3" /><kp id="4" /><kp id="5" /><kp id="6" /><kp id="7" /><kp id="8" /><kp id="9" /><kp id="10" /><kp id="11" /><kp id="12" /><kp id="13" /><kp id="14" /><kp id="15" /><kp id="16" /><kp id="17" /><kp id="18" /><kp id="19" /><kp id="20" /><kp id="21" /><kp id="22" /><kp id="23" /><kp id="24" /><kp id="25" /><kp id="26" /><kp id="27" /><kp id="28" /><kp id="29" /><kp id="30" /><kp id="31" /><kp id="32" /></kps><opon><op id="1" /><op id="2" /><op id="3" /><op id="4" /><op id="5" /><op id="6" /><op id="7" /><op id="8" /><op id="9" /><op id="10" /><op id="11" /><op id="12" /><op id="13" /><op id="14" /><op id="15" /><op id="16" /><op id="17" /><op id="18" /><op id="19" /><op id="20" /><op id="21" /><op id="22" /><op id="23" /><op id="24" /><op id="25" /><op id="26" /><op id="27" /><op id="28" /><op id="29" /><op id="30" /><op id="31" /><op id="32" /></opon><opoff><op id="1" /><op id="2" /><op id="3" /><op id="4" /><op id="5" /><op id="6" /><op id="7" /><op id="8" /><op id="9" /><op id="10" /><op id="11" /><op id="12" /><op id="13" /><op id="14" /><op id="15" /><op id="16" /><op id="17" /><op id="18" /><op id="19" /><op id="20" /><op id="21" /><op id="22" /><op id="23" /><op id="24" /><op id="25" /><op id="26" /><op id="27" /><op id="28" /><op id="29" /><op id="30" /><op id="31" /><op id="32" /></opoff><usage>255</usage><startdate /><enddate /><starttime>0:00</starttime><endtime>23:59</endtime><tzd /><ag>1</ag></user><user id="2"><name>Fred Dagg</name><pin></pin><tag>xxxxxxxxx</tag><type><opt id="tag">Prox Tag</opt></type><partns><pn id="1" /><pn id="2" /></partns><access><opt id="awarm" /><opt id="awdis" /><opt id="stdis" /><opt id="egrs" /></access><priv /><misc /><tzs /><kps><kp id="1" /><kp id="2" /><kp id="3" /><kp id="4" /><kp id="5" /><kp id="6" /><kp id="7" /><kp id="8" /><kp id="9" /><kp id="10" /><kp id="11" /><kp id="12" /><kp id="13" /><kp id="14" /><kp id="15" /><kp id="16" /><kp id="17" /><kp id="18" /><kp id="19" /><kp id="20" /><kp id="21" /><kp id="22" /><kp id="23" /><kp id="24" /><kp id="25" /><kp id="26" /><kp id="27" /><kp id="28" /><kp id="29" /><kp id="30" /><kp id="31" /><kp id="32" /></kps><opon><op id="8" /><op id="11" /><op id="13" /><op id="14" /><op id="15" /><op id="16" /></opon><opoff><op id="13" /></opoff><usage>255</usage><startdate /><enddate /><starttime>0:00</starttime><endtime>0:00</endtime><tzd /><ag>0</ag></user>
```

If I try to make this file with excel, of course I run out of columns!

Out of a csv, I get:

```
<user id="1"><name>Bevan</name><pin>xxxx</pin><tag>xxxxxxxx</tag><type><opt id="kbdortag">Keypad or Tag</opt></type><partns><pn id="1" /><pn id="2" /></partns><access><opt id="awarm" /><opt id="awdis" /><opt id="stdis" /><opt id="egrs" /><opt id="view" /></access><priv><opt id="own" /><opt id="otr" /><opt id="all" /><opt id="phn" /><opt id="clk" /><opt id="dtmf" /><opt id="lrn" /><opt id="cbk" /></priv><misc /><tzs /><kps><kp id="1" /><kp id="2" /><kp id="3" /><kp id="4" /><kp id="5" /><kp id="6" /><kp id="7" /><kp id="8" /><kp id="9" /><kp id="10" /><kp id="11" /><kp id="12" /><kp id="13" /><kp id="14" /><kp id="15" /><kp id="16" /><kp id="17" /><kp id="18" /><kp id="19" /><kp id="20" /><kp id="21" /><kp id="22" /><kp id="23" /><kp id="24" /><kp id="25" /><kp id="26" /><kp id="27" /><kp id="28" /><kp id="29" /><kp id="30" /><kp id="31" /><kp id="32" /></kps><opon><op id="1" /><op id="2" /><op id="3" /><op id="4" /><op id="5" /><op id="6" /><op id="7" /><op id="8" /><op id="9" /><op id="10" /><op id="11" /><op id="12" /><op id="13" /><op id="14" /><op id="15" /><op id="16" /><op id="17" /><op id="18" /><op id="19" /><op id="20" /><op id="21" /><op id="22" /><op id="23" /><op id="24" /><op id="25" /><op id="26" /><op id="27" /><op id="28" /><op id="29" /><op id="30" /><op id="31" /><op id="32" /></opon><opoff><op id="1" /><op id="2" /><op id="3" /><op id="4" /><op id="5" /><op id="6" /><op id="7" /><op id="8" /><op id="9" /><op id="10" /><op id="11" /><op id="12" /><op id="13" /><op id="14" /><op id="15" /><op id="16" /><op id="17" /><op id="18" /><op id="19" /><op id="20" /><op id="21" /><op id="22" /><op id="23" /><op id="24" /><op id="25" /><op id="26" /><op id="27" /><op id="28" /><op id="29" /><op id="30" /><op id="31" /><op id="32" /></opoff><usage>255</usage><startdate /><enddate /><starttime>0:00</starttime><endtime>23:59</endtime><tzd /><ag>1</ag></user>
<user id="2"><name>Fred</name><pin></pin><tag>xxxxxxxxx</tag><type><opt id="tag">Prox Tag</opt></type><partns><pn id="1" /><pn id="2" /></partns><access><opt id="awarm" /><opt id="awdis" /><opt id="stdis" /><opt id="egrs" /></access><priv /><misc /><tzs /><kps><kp id="1" /><kp id="2" /><kp id="3" /><kp id="4" /><kp id="5" /><kp id="6" /><kp id="7" /><kp id="8" /><kp id="9" /><kp id="10" /><kp id="11" /><kp id="12" /><kp id="13" /><kp id="14" /><kp id="15" /><kp id="16" /><kp id="17" /><kp id="18" /><kp id="19" /><kp id="20" /><kp id="21" /><kp id="22" /><kp id="23" /><kp id="24" /><kp id="25" /><kp id="26" /><kp id="27" /><kp id="28" /><kp id="29" /><kp id="30" /><kp id="31" /><kp id="32" /></kps><opon><op id="8" /><op id="11" /><op id="13" /><op id="14" /><op id="15" /><op id="16" /></opon><opoff><op id="13" /></opoff><usage>255</usage><startdate /><enddate /><starttime>0:00</starttime><endtime>0:00</endtime><tzd /><ag>0</ag></user>
```

I need to get the two hundred lines, and make them into one single line. Whew!

Comment: Could you please post a data example? The input you got and the expected output would be helpful

Comment: Why not just use `Find and Replace`?

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld but please help me further. Find and replace .... what? What do I type into Notepad's Find & Replace to signify a line break?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns i've added a sample

Comment: First your so called csv file is not a csv but a plain text file. Excel comes with a very nice macro language called VBA which is in fact an almost full featured MS Visual Basic. I currently have no Excel at hand, but it should be easy to use an Excel macro to read one text file and write to another one.

Comment: @Bevan, your expected output is 2846 chars longs, but your input, the chars related to user1 are 1894 and to user2 are 947. 1894 + 947 = 2841. There are a difference of 5 chars between your expected output and your input. It should be the same, am I right? Also. Would not work just concatenate cells?

Comment: `alt-010` or `alt-012` or both. The digits need to be typed on the numeric keypad.

Comment: And don't forget you are limited to 32,767 characters in a single XL cell

Comment: @RonRosenfeld can you pop your suggestion in as an answer so I can vote it as the solution please?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns yes the users have varying length names and privilege options so the strings are of varying lengths

Comment: @SergeBallesta good point re CSV. You're right it actually is plain text, hadn't noticed it properly myself. I'll update the question title to prevent misleading people. VBA is over my head, sorry. Ron twigged what I needed and that worked nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find and replace.  `alt-010` and/or `alt-012` will find linefeed and carriage return.  Replace with nothing or space.